# How i can secure hypervisor with svirt?

Tags: openstack, virtualization, selinux, hypervisor

I'm working on project that aims to secure openstack, i want to secure virtualization, i’ve heard a lot about securing hypervisors so that I became afraid, what i understood that selinux does not require admin intervention since svirt generates automatic labels for instances and their disk image, so why there is to much debate about svirt and hypervisor security while putting selinux in mode enforcing is enough ??

Answer (score 0):

Note that another option is to secure OpenStack applications using secure enclaves with a hardware root of trust, using technologies such as Intel SGX. That would provide hardware-grade security for the application, instead of rooting the trust in the hypervisor.